# comparing values of two arrays if exist or not

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have this code which is to check in the two arrays  and print out the values that dont exist in the other array. I think the way i did it is not the most efficient way to do it hence can anyone offer a better OOP way to write this code in Java?

Thanks

```
 public class Calculate {
        static int [] x = {1,2,4,6,7};
        static int [] y = {2,3,4,6,7}; 
        static boolean xflag = true;
        static boolean yflag = true;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
            {

            for (int b=0;  b<y.length; b++)
                {
                    if(x[i]!= y[b])
                    {
                        xflag= false;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xflag = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if(xflag==false)
                {
                    System.out.println(x[i] +" does not exist in array 2");
                }

            }


            for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
            {

            for (int b=0;  b<y.length; b++)
                {
                    if(y[i]!= x[b])
                    {
                        yflag= false;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yflag = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if(yflag==false)
                {
                    System.out.println(y[i] +" does not exist in array1");
                }

            }





        }


    }
```

Comment: The Collections framework has `removeAll` and `retainAll` methods that could be useful here. Don't operate on arrays directly, though.

Comment: Is it guarenteed that the arrays contain the same number of elements or is sorted?

Comment: i dont get your question Tyler.

Comment: I was asking if you knew whether the two arrays would always be sorted and/or contain the same number of elements. Such as both arrays containing 5 elements. However, rather than posting another answer, I would suggest using Jayesh's answer if you are unsure of the array types you will be using or just want to achieve a state of code-reuse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Collection class removeAll method

```
  String original[] = { "1","2","3","4","6"};
     String testStr[] = { "1","2","3","5","7" };
        List origList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(original));
        List testList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(testStr));

        System.out.println(origList.removeAll(testList));
        System.out.println(origList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use Apache's `CollectionUtils` for this purpose if you want an abstraction from the implementation logic.E.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1=Arrays.asList(1,2,4,6,7);
        List<Integer> list2=Arrays.asList(2,3,4,6,7);

    System.out.println(CollectionUtils.disjunction(list1,list2));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use java collection framework, Many function are there,
here is simple example check it.

```
public static void main(String a[]){

    List<String> sl = new ArrayList<String>();
    sl.add("apple");
    sl.add("java");
    sl.add("c++");
    sl.add("unix");
    sl.add("orange");
    sl.add("airtel");
    List<String> tl = new ArrayList<String>();
    tl.add("job");
    tl.add("oracle");
    tl.add("jungle");
    tl.add("cricket");
    boolean isCommon = Collections.disjoint(sl,tl);
    System.out.println("Does not found any common elements? "+isCommon);
    tl.add("java");
    isCommon = Collections.disjoint(sl,tl);
    System.out.println("Does not found any common elements? "+isCommon);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can code this way

```
List<Integer> array1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,6,7);
List<Integer> array2 = Arrays.asList(2,3,4,6,7);

List<Integer> disjointArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer value : array1) {
    if (!array2.contains(value)) {
        disjointArray.add(value);
    }
}
```

And then you can print disjointArray or do whatever manipulation you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here a running example using Javas Collection classes:

```
public class Disjunction {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //Some data preparation
        List<Integer> list1=Arrays.asList(1,2,4);
        List<Integer> list2=Arrays.asList(5,2,8);

        //Here calculating data1-data2 and data2-data1, collect all list items
        //that are in data1 or in data2 but not in both.
        List<Integer> data1 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
        data1.removeAll(list2);
        List<Integer> data2 = new ArrayList<>(list2);
        data2.removeAll(list1);

        //Merging both results. data1 contains now exclusive or of list1 and list2
        data1.addAll(data2);

        System.out.println("exclusive or is " + data1);
    }
}
```

It prints out

```
exclusive or is [1, 4, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following program that checks two arrays for numbers they both have and numbers they don't have:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayDifferentiater {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ori = { 1, 5, 4, 8, 6, 65, 16, 6, 575, 64, 561, 57, 57 };
        int[] che = { 1, 4, 8, 6 };
        sort(ori, che);
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a, int[] b) {
        /**
         * 'foundNum' contains the numbers which exists in both array. 
         * 'notFoundNum' contains the numbers which exists in only first array.
         */
        ArrayList<Integer> foundNum = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> notFoundNum = new ArrayList<>();

        // First for loop starts
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            
            // Second for loop starts
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {

                /**
                 * Check if array 1 contains value of array 2. 
                 * If contains than add it to "foundNum" arraylist.
                 */
                if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                    foundNum.add(a[i]);

                    // Remove the number which exists in both arrays from "notFoundNum" arraylist.

                    if (notFoundNum.contains(a[i])) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < notFoundNum.size(); k++) {
                            if (notFoundNum.get(k) == a[i]) {
                                notFoundNum.remove(k);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                    
                } // First if block ends

                /**
                 * Checks if a not found number does not exists in 'notFoundNum' arraylist (to reduce redundancy)
                 * then adds a not found number to 'notFoundNum' arraylist
                 * */
                if (!notFoundNum.contains(a[i]))
                    notFoundNum.add(a[i]);
                
            } // Second for loop ends
            
        } // First for loop ends
        
        System.out.println("Found Numbers : " + foundNum);
        System.out.println("Not Found Numbers : " + notFoundNum);
    }

}
```

Here is the output for the above program:

```
Found Numbers : [1, 4, 8, 6, 6]
Not Found Numbers : [5, 65, 16, 575, 64, 561, 57]
```